# Need a little guidance on counting and calculating sum of rows.

Tags: php, mysql, loops, sum

I'm making a little voting tool (voting from 1 to 5) and I have the votes stored in a DB. I'm wondering, what is the best manner to count all the rows (of a specific post ID) and then calculate the sum of those specific rows so that I can display the results.

i.e

```
Results: 3.5 / 5
(total votes: 1047)
```

Should I use a PHP loop or MYSQL sum?

Comment: In general I try to have the database do as much work for me as it can, and simply output the results. So, if your data is set up to be easily summed, do it on the DB side.

Comment: Stored in the DB how? What's the table schema?

Comment: Any examples of that?

Comment: They are just INT values of 1-5

Comment: Not specifically without a table schema, but AVG() and SUM() will be good functions to look into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT AVG(vote), COUNT(vote) FROM vote_table WHERE post_id = 1234;
```

The first. column gives your average out of 5 and the count the total votes. To get all the stats at once:

```
SELECT AVG(vote), COUNT(vote), post_id FROM vote_table GROUP BY post_id;
```